# Typo3 Extbase Edit/Update Action does not accept empty checkbox for bool/int field

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-12.x

Typo3 v12.4

I have a model with boolean fields, defined as integers in the database and in the model and as checkboxes in the TCA.
I have a form to edit the model in the frontend, the boolean fields have checkboxes with value=1.
When I submit the form without checking the checkboxes, an Oops-error shows up and the error log file says something like """Exception while property mapping at property path "": Expected argument of type "int", "null" given at property path "finalized"."""

In Typo3 versions prior to 12, no error occured in such cases. It simply ignored fields which were not present in the form and kept the values unchanged.

Is there a short way to tell new extbase about this field? Do I have to add an InitializeAction-Method? Did I forgot anything in the TCA? Should the fields be nullable?

(With select fields (two options: 0 and 1) in the form, the error does not occur, but this is not the way boolean fields should be represented in a form.)

Comment: If you want to pass a property without a value (=> `null`), the setter-method of that property should accept `null` (and convert it to `0` in the model).

Comment: Please show your setter method of your model, the TCA configuration of your field and the HTML code for the field of your form.

Comment: The model says
`protected int $finalized = 0;
public function getFinalized(): int {
 return $this->finalized;
}
public function setFinalized(int $finalized = 0): void {
 $this->finalized = $finalized;
}`
so missing or null parameter in setter should be replaced by int=0, shouldn't it?

Comment: No. `int $finalized = 0`expects the parameter to be an integer, and throws an exception if the parameter does not match. `setFinalized($finalized = 0)` would fill a missing/empty parameter. With `setFinalized(?int $finalized = 0)`  the parameter would be of a nullable int type and `null` can be passed to the method.

Comment: Sounds logical. Thank you very much!